# how to make a selection for the dictionary?

Tags: python, html, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

help please write xpath-expression.

html:

```
<div class="TabItem">
    <p><strong>Product Composition</strong></p>
    <p>93% Polyamide 7% Elastane</p>
    <p>Lining: 100% Polyester</p><p>Dress Length: 90 cm</p>

    <p><strong>Product Attributes;</strong></p>
    <p>: Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side</p>
    <p>Lining Type: Full Lining</p>
</div>
```

this need to get the following html dictionary:

```
data['Product Composition'] = '93% Polyamide 7% Elastane Lining: 100% Polyester</p><p>Dress Length: 90 cm'
data['Product Attributes;'] = ': Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side Lining Type: Full Lining'
```

it is important that the number of elements can vary. ie you need a universal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get every `strong` tag inside `p`, then get it's parent and next parent's siblings until there is another `p` tag with `strong` tag inside or no more siblings left:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring


html_data = """<div class="TabItem">
    <p><strong>Product Composition</strong></p>
    <p>93% Polyamide 7% Elastane</p>
    <p>Lining: 100% Polyester</p><p>Dress Length: 90 cm</p>

    <p><strong>Product Attributes;</strong></p>
    <p>: Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side</p>
    <p>Lining Type: Full Lining</p>
</div>"""

tree = fromstring(html_data)
data = {}
for strong in tree.xpath('//p/strong'):
    parent = strong.getparent()

    description = []
    next_p = parent.getnext()
    while next_p is not None and not next_p.xpath('.//strong'):
        description.append(next_p.text)
        next_p = next_p.getnext()

    data[strong.text] = " ".join(description)

print data
```

prints:

```
{'Product Composition': '93% Polyamide 7% Elastane Lining: 100% Polyester', 
 'Product Attributes;': ': Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side Lining Type: Full Lining'}
```

Comment: but elements <p> and <strong> may be a different number. 2 now, but may be 10, and 1